# Install MSSQL Using Composer

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, drupal, composer-php

I am migrating a Drupal site to another server and keep getting HTTP 500 error in the browser. When I investigate the PHP error log, I see that there is

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

in one of  the files. I am on a Linux environment and have Composer installed. Is  there a way to install the mssql extension using the Composer? Alternatively, what is an efficient way to install MSSQL extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `SQLSRV` functions are [only available on Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) machines.

you can try using the [ODBC functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php), after installing the [drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx) but you will have to rewrite your code to use them.

if you happen to be running Ubuntu, here's a [script](https://github.com/admonkey/prefage/blob/master/apps.install/ubuntu/mssql.odbc.driver.bash) for installation.

Comment: Are you telling me that if I have a Linux web server on one  machine and a MSSQL database on a a different (Windows) server then there is no way to make them work with each other aside from what you have specified?

Comment: it's painful, right? microsoft even stopped support for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which otherwise would be the most portable solution for dbms platforms. I use ODBC all the time for this, but **CAUTION** the prepared statements don't work on Linux even with MS drivers. you'll have to do custom escaping and stick to exclusively using parameterized stored procedures.

Comment: one last caveat I've discovered is the datatype `NVARCHAR(MAX)` returns void in query result sets, so you'll have to `CAST as TEXT` in order to work around that.

Comment: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql.html looks like it's available for asp.net 5 on Linux, I might have misread though. But yes, it looks like there is no way to do this yet using composer and PHP. Maybe a Web service that takes PHP input and converts it to MSSQL commands and then hands back the result? Kinda a bad work around though. Might be easier to switch to another SQL server?

Comment: @Caperneoignis I don't see linux mentioned anywhere on that page. is that the right link?

Comment: One second let me find a better link for yea. Asp.net 5 with MVC 6 is supposed to be able to run on linux. I may have clicked out from where they mention linux.

Comment: Okay, I'm putting two and two together here, since MVC6 is still new along with mono, you kinda going in to uncharted waters here. MSSQL does not run on Linux for what I can see. The driver however, is available via Nuget and that should be able to operate on linux. [Issues](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+mono) and [FAQ](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/nuget-faq) also the gallery link [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=sqlserver) I have run a MVC6 app on a linux system, so I know it can be done.

Comment: However, I was using MySQL and not MSSQL.

Comment: [MSSQL_Linux](http://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2016/03/07/announcing-sql-server-on-linux/#sm.0000emwysre55f6r10q1ztqaaabw4) Announcement about MSSQL for Linux.

Comment: There is no known issues with the mssql drivers on the Issues section of Nuget, so I'm assuming it works. Just to clear that up, since I wasn't before.

Comment: This blog supposedly has a way to connect to a mssql server [link](https://davejamesmiller.com/blog/connecting-php-to-microsoft-sql-server-on-linux)

Comment: Am I missing something subtle about this question? I use the `sqlsrv` functions on linux all the time, just need the php sybase extension installed. Never had a problem with it

Comment: @Clive I've never heard of sybase, but that sounds awesome. Can you share a link to some documentation, or better yet post an answer?

Comment: @Caperneoignis the links to ASP.NET MVC on linux are interesting, but doesn't help the OP since they're trying to get a PHP app to run. As for the MSSQL_Linux announcement, it says "targeting availability in mid-2017" which might be helpful for future readers too, but I'm not sure if that necessarily includes methods to access from PHP, although I certainly hope so.

Comment: Oh no, I agreed with you that there no composer way of communicating with php, unless you want to make some type of communication with a MVC 6 app. In other words, agreeing with your observation that there is no straight way of communicating with MSSQL. I was just providing another possible work around. In other words, just trying to give some more information.

Comment: @Caperneoignis with regards to your post on using FreeTDS and php5-sybase to enable the [MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) functions, I noticed that for `mssql_connect` "This function was REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0." which still might be a viable option for some. 
@Clive Just curious too, if that's what you were referring to, or does the sybase extension enable both `MSSQL` and `SQLSRV` functions?

Comment: 5.6 should be supported for a while. Hopefully, long enough for a driver to come available for the Linux variant of MSSQL. I know, kinda wishful thinking, but I'd bet money on it.